# Tabs with custom field sets on record pages

Tags: lightning

I would like to customize the contact record page to display different fields under different tabs on the page for organizational purposes, instead of displaying all of the custom fields under the standard 'details' component. I understand ( i think) how to divide the page into tabs (see photo below), but how do I go about putting different contact fields within the different tabs on the record page?  For example, I want different fields under the 'home/correspondence' tab than those that display under the standard 'details' tab or that I would put in any other tabs I have on the record page.

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Comment: I think this question should not have been closed, and is perfectly clear w/o edits. The answer: There is no declarative functionality available to put fields on different sub tabs of a Lightning Record Page. You would have to create either a Visualforce page (enabled for Salesforce 1 and Lightning Pages), or a Lightning Component, with the fields that you want to show on the tab. Then remove those fields from the Detail section via the Page Layout editor. But the only out-of-the box way to put editable, record-level fields on a Lightning Record Page is with the Details component.

Comment: Have reopened, because I believe @ThomasTaylor's comment has value, and should be available as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no declarative functionality available to put fields on different sub tabs of a Lightning Record Page. You would have to create either a Visualforce page (enabled for Salesforce 1 and Lightning Pages), or a Lightning Component, with the fields that you want to show on the tab. Then remove those fields from the Detail section via the Page Layout editor. But the only out-of-the box way to put editable, record-level fields on a Lightning Record Page is with the Details component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a New action per tab on the object and select action type as **update a record**. After that edit the layout on the action to show the fields you need.

Now,you can now create a tab on lightning page and put the action there. This should solve your issue.